# How to make certain conceal symbols get highlighted differently than others?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, conceal

I’ve recently tried to make my python more readable using the conceal functionality. So now I went from this [image: without conceal]

to this [image: with conceal].

Now what really bugs me here is that `ƒ`, `¶`,the `¥` sign, the `ℤ` and  symbols and the variable name subscripts don’t have the correct syntax highlighting. They take their highlighting from the conceal syntax group. That means that only one highlight is possible for all of them. Now I have looked through the forum only to find similar questions like this with no answers.

So my question would be how to override syntax highlighting for specific conceal symbols and if it is even possible.

Comment: I should not that I’m using Neovim version 0.4.3.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Afaik there is only one conceal highlight group, but neovim may have changed this