# Using multiple syntax groups for the vim conceal functionallity

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I’ve recently tried using vim conceal to "symbolify" my code. Although it looks very nice there is a heavy drawback: all the concealed syntax that is turned into pretty unicode is always highlighted with one color. This is a no-go for me, because different colors let you recognize the structure of your code faster than by just reading it. I have looked into this quite deeply, I might say, but alas, I have always stumbled upon the same problem, which is that there is only one conceal group for syntax highlighting. I have already asked in the vi–vim forums, but without success.

(TL;DR)
So, my question would be, if there is a definitive way to add multiple syntax groups for the conceal symbols, except for modifying the source code itself, which is not my kind if undertaking.
Also I don’t know if it makes any difference that I use Neovim (v0.4.3) instead of Vim.

Comment: No, this is not possible

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/27480/10604: please dont ask the same question multiple times. If you need to update the old one, you can use the [edit] functionality. See also [ask]